# CSS Background Image Not working in SP 2013, but works Locally

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

This works locally

```
body { 
    /*background: Gainsboro;*/
    background: url(../dt_images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

When I edit the master page html file on the server for SP 2013, it doesn't show (all of my other override CSS works though...). You cannot see the cloudy background.

```
body {  
    background: url(../DT_CustomFiles/DT_IMAGES/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

Does SP 2013 not allow background images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uploading the image to Site Assets in your SharePoint site and edit the link in css to point to that location. It should fix it.

Comment: Okay now it seems like it's loading, but just for a second... then it seems to disappear, or be overriden by a white SP standard background color.

Comment: What happens if you add "!important" ?

Comment: "background: url(../dt_images/bg.jpg) !important no-repeat center center fixed;"

Comment: Ah figured it out. Need `!important;`